# How to switch https traffic from 1 web server to another one. IPTABLES issue

Tags: linux, tcp, routes, iptables, varnish

Here is my configuration.
I have varnish listening to port 80 and 2 web server (tomcat) on port 8080 and 8081 and https 4430 and 4431.

HTTP traffic goes from varnish to 1 web server. When I need to upgrade my app, I shut down one tomcat, upgrade the code, restart and change the varnish configuration to go to the upgraded tomcat.

I need to do the same for HTTP traffic. It's a small amount of traffic and I don't need caching, so I though I could just use iptables.

So I added a rule like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 4430
```

and when I need to switch to the other tomcat, I do:

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 4430 
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 4431
```

It seemed to work but after I few days all the machine has connection problems. Varnish is not connecting to tomcat, dns lookup do not work, etc.

I found in /var/log/messages thousands of:

```
Mar 27 10:04:15 ip-10-72-254-31 kernel: [2112599.753509] nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.
```

Shutting down iptables seems to work to fix the connection problems.

So, can I use iptables in the way I'm using it?
How can I prevent "table full, dropping packet" issue?
What else can I use to redirect my https traffic?

Answer (score 0):

We use iptables extensively and never faced NAT tables filling up; The only difference I see is that we are using slightly different rules using the DNAT target (even for localhost) rather than REDIRECT.

`/sbin/iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp  --dport 443 -j DNAT --to :4430`

(our kernels are 2.6.32 and higher - iptables 1.4.3.1 and higher)

**EDIT**

You can try making some adjustments to the nf_conntrack tacble (which tracks all opened connections).

The first one would be to reduce the time a connection can be tracked to a more sensible value, like one day. Something like:

`sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established=86400`

You can also try to increase the size of the table

`sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=65535`

Restarting your network interfaces should be enough to use these new values.

Finally you will probably need to make those modifications to sysctl.conf to survive the next reboot.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, I was waiting for other replies. Here http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html I read that REDIRECT "is exactly equivalent to doing DNAT". What exactly mean that the NAT tables fill up?

Comment: See my edits above on adjustments you could try on the conntrack table.

Answer (score 0):

To answer "*What else can I use to redirect my https traffic?*": You can use `rinetd`. Like `iptables`, it can be used to redirect TCP connections at port level, but it's way simpler to configure.

In essence, you would put this line to `/etc/rinetd.conf`:

```
10.72.254.31  443    10.72.254.31  4430
```

And exchange it for this when you want to switch over to the second web server:

```
10.72.254.31  443    10.72.254.31  4431
```

and after every such change, restart `rinetd` with:

```
service rinetd restart
```

Just make sure that nothing is listening on port 443 when enabling these, as else forwarding will fail and your `/var/log/rinetd.log` will be flooded with messages like `22/Mar/2013:19:35:47 0.0.0.0 0 (null) 0 0 0 accept-failed -` [[details](http://ma.juii.net/blog/redirect-traffic-to-server)].